# Xcode-beta error when try emulate with Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm try to get started with Ionic but when I emulate with 'ionic emulate ios' the console show me this
issue:

```
No target specified for emulator. Deploying to iPhone-6 simulator
2015-06-19 10:07:59.674 ios-sim[771:9114] stderrPath:   /Users/damivazbien/myApp/platforms/ios/cordova/console.log
2015-06-19 10:07:59.674 ios-sim[771:9114] stdoutPath:  /Users/damivazbien/myApp/platforms/ios/cordova/console.log
2015-06-19 10:08:00.753 ios-sim[771:9114] [MT] DVTAssertions: Warning in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/DVTFrameworks/DVTFrameworks-8114.19/DVTFoundation/PlugInArchitecture/PlugInManager/DVTPlugInManager.m:257
Details:  Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.DVTFoundation.DevicePlatformMapping
Object:   <DVTPlugInManager: 0x7fe8faca4b50>
Method:   -extensionPointWithIdentifier:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fe8fac105e0>{number = 1, name = main}
Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning  message and any useful information you can provide.
Session could not be started: Error Domain=DTiPhoneSimulatorErrorDomain  Code=2 "Timed out waiting for device to boot" UserInfo=0x7fe8fad0c7a0  {NSLocalizedDescription=Timed out waiting for device to boot}
Error code 1 for command: ios-sim with args: launch,/Users/damivazbien/myApp/platforms/ios/build/emulator/myApp.app,-- devicetypeid,com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-6,-- stderr,/Users/damivazbien/myApp/platforms/ios/cordova/console.log,-- stdout,/Users/damivazbien/myApp/platforms/ios/cordova/console.log,--exit
Error: /Users/damivazbien/myApp/platforms/ios/cordova/run: Command failed with exit code 2
at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:134:23)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
at maybeClose (child_process.js:766:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:833:5)
```

Now I have installed the last Xcode beta

Answer (score 2):

Did you check details in stderr logs?

```
%project_name%/platforms/ios/cordova/console.log
```

If you use ios9 emulator and see white screen, possible that you faced with the problem that ios9 enforced to use https.

Dirty way is just update to xcode project config plist to disable ATS

```
platforms/ios/%project_name%/%project_name%-Info.plist
```

You can disable Apple Transport Security by adding this to config file

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string></string>
```

Comment: His simulator won't boot. It's not a build or app runtime error. I don't htink Apple Transport Security has anything to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

I get a similar error message in Xamarin Studio when building using the Xcode 7 SDK. Have you tried running against Xcode 6.3.2 instead, or is there another good reason why you are running Ionic with the Xcode 7 beta?

In my experience it's better to keep your environment as familiar as possible when trying out new tools, there's less unfamiliar stuff going on and hence easier to troubleshoot.

Comment: It's possible OP installed OSX 10.11 betas, which means OP can only run Xcode 7 betas, Xcode 6 is not compatible with El Capitan. I've done the same thing and am receiving the same error in RubyMotion.

Comment: Found I could temporarily add the following to my Rakefile for RubyMotion: `app.info_plist['NSAppTransportSecurity'] = { 'NSAllowsArbitraryLoads' => true }`. Must remember to do the right thing and add proper exceptions to info.plist for production build though.